# Customize group permissions in django?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I need to make role-based authentication. Firstly, I made group permissions for all my apps. I assigned some of them to role according to role's ability.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class Role(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

[image: driver role with access]

Here you can a see driver role which has access on some group permissions (in fact they are just names of groups)

Now I have a user model:

```
class Users(AbstractUser):
    role = models.ForeignKey(
        Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='roles', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.username)
```

I don't want to pick group permissions every time when I created a new staff user. I just want to set a role to a user and it should automatically pick all permissions based on selected role's groups. How to customize groups in django models?

Comment: Why not make a single `Group` with all permissions? I don't really see how a role is (much) differen than a group. You basically make a many-to-many-to-many which is in essence not much more than a "labeled" many-to-many.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Hi. It is just what my manager asked. ) The point is I have group permissions for each app. (let's say I have 10 apps, so 10 groups of permissions). Then, I have roles like operator, driver, content-manager and etc. Let's say in future if superadmin wants to give a permission of 'foo' group to all operators, he should assign them one-by-one to all operators or just add those permissions to another group. The point is you just add this group to a role and it will be available to all users (who has this role) automatically.